# How do you code the responsive menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do this responsive menu.

[cuppcomputing](http://cuppcomputing.net/)

On the desktop version, it will show the whole panel when its meet max-width:600px ( tablet and mobile size). It just show the title, and then when you click it, it will show the menu inner. If u resize the browser you can go back to desktop version and mobile version. I don't want to use a plugin.

I did try the desktop version, it works. I don't know how to make it responsive. When my breakpoint is 600px and I click on a different .menuCol h2 it will show and hide. When my breakpoint is larger than 600px ( when I resize my browser) some of the .menuList are hidden.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k48m102L/)

```js
function menuToggle() {
  $('#menuBtn').click(function() {
    var menuBtn = $('#menuBtn');
    var menuInner = $('.menuInner');

    if ($(menuInner).is(':hidden')) {
      $(menuBtn).text('close');
    } else {
      $(menuBtn).text('menu');
    }

    $(menuInner).fadeToggle(200);
  });
}

menuToggle();


function menuMobile() {
  $(".menuCol h2").click(function() {

    $(".menuList").slideUp();

    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  });

}


menuMobile();
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #434141;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#toggleMenu {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#menuBtn {
  background-color: #fa7361;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #434141;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menuInner {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #cce9ec;
  padding: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menuInner .menuCol {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 22.5%;
  float: left;
}
.menuInner .menuCol h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.menuInner li {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-right: 3.3%;
}
.menuInner li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.menuList {
  display: block;
}
.menuList a:hover {
  color: #fa7361;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #fa7361;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .menuInner .menuCol {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menuInner .menuCol h2 {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .menuInner .menuCol h2:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fa7361;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #fa7361;
  }
  .menuCol:last-child h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .menuList {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggleMenu">
  <a id="menuBtn" href="#">menu</a>
  <ul class="menuInner">
    <li class="menuCol">
      <h2>Living Room</h2>
      <ul class="menuList">
        <li><a href="#">sofas & loveseats</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">chairs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">benches</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">bookcases & shelving</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">all living room</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuCol">
      <h2>Bedroom</h2>
      <ul class="menuList">
        <li><a href="#">beds</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">mattresses</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">daybeds & sleepers</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">floor mirrors</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">all bedroom</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuCol">
      <h2>Home Office</h2>
      <ul class="menuList">
        <li><a href="#">desks</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">desk chairs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">office storage</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">display ledges</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">all office</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuCol">
      <h2>Dining Room</h2>
      <ul class="menuList">
        <li><a href="#">dining tables</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dining chairs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">bar & counter stools</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dining benches</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">all dining</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media queries and restructure your CSS to make it work with mobile phones or tablets. Research media queries.

Comment: so its not my jquery problem?

Comment: You have your  toggle menu's max width set to 1000px. This will most certainly not work with mobile devices. You need to set multiple media queries and structure your max width to those devices.

Comment: can u help me? i dont get it

Comment: A media query is established in your CSS file. You change only the data that is needed to be changed with different screen types. If you code a lot of your CSS in percentages, a lot of it will transfer over well to different devices. However, there are certain things you may choose to not include with a mobile device. For instance, if you have an image gallery, you may wish to not include it. You can create media queries inside of your existing external CSS file or you can create a new one. You start of by declaring a max width and then change any other pertinent data as you need to.

Comment: Most people only use two media queries but you can add others. y

Comment: "large" css here

@media only screen and (max-width:800px)
{
"medium" css changes here
}

The AT symbol media only screen and (max-width:480px)
{
"small" css changes here
}

Comment: my problem is when my breakpoint is max-width 600px , it shows the mobile menu, when  i click on each .menuCol h2, and then go back to larger than 600px, some of my .menuList are hidden( the one that i clicked)

Comment: Also when  go back to larger than 600px, I can click .menuCol h2. Its not supposed to click (.menuCol h2) . .menuCol h2 is clickable for smaller than 600px ( mobile menu) ...

Comment: That's why you set up media queries to structure each of these changes differently. For example on my site, I have my normal desktop version menubar set at a width of 960px, but in my small media query I have the width set to 100%.

Comment: I try to set my width to 1000px for my menu, my small media query i set it to width 100%. but it doesn't work. can u show me how on jsfiddle?

Comment: did u see my css? i just post it

Comment: Hey Paul, what's wrong with my css? can u take a look?

Comment: i still can't find the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
#toggleMenu { text-align: center; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }

#menuBtn { background-color: #fa7361; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 15px; color: #434141; padding: 2px 6px; margin-bottom: 24px; display: inline-block; }

.menuInner { text-align: left; background-color: #cce9ec; padding: 5%; overflow: hidden; }
.menuInner .menuCol { margin-bottom: 0; width: 22.5%; float: left; }
.menuInner .menuCol h2 { font-size: 15px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 20px; }
.menuInner li { margin-bottom: 8px; margin-right: 3.3%; }
.menuInner li:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; margin-right: 0; }

.menuList { display: block; }
.menuList a:hover { color: #fa7361; border-bottom: 1px dotted #fa7361; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { #toggleMenu { width: 100%; }
  .menuInner .menuCol { float: none; width: 100%; text-align: center; }
  .menuInner .menuCol h2 { cursor: pointer; }
  .menuInner .menuCol h2:hover { display: inline-block; color: #fa7361; border-bottom: 1px dotted #fa7361; }
  .menuCol:last-child h2 { margin-bottom: 0; }
  .menuList { display: none; } }
```